# How to add ref keys in Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, database-migration

I would like to add `receipt_id` as foreign key in `hospitalization` tables

I tried below command.

`rails g migration AddReceiptToHospitalizations receipt:references`

migration file is like this.

```
class AddReceiptToHospitalizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :hospitalizations, :receipt, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

When I tried`rails db:migrate`I suffere below errors.

```
== 20191116102056 AddReceiptRefToHospitalizations: migrating ==================
-- add_reference(:hospitalizations, :receipt, {:foreign_key=>true})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'calendar_test_development.#sql-fa0_1c' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE `hospitalizations` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_325b2e6b31`
FOREIGN KEY (`receipt_id`)
  REFERENCES `receipts` (`id`)
```

If someone has already experienced such error,please let me know how to fix.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the whole error?

Comment: You can write like this too..
add_column :hospitalizations, :receipt_id, integer, foreign: true. This will create a column receipt_id in hospitalization with column type BIGINT and adds index too.